# Utility Theory: Risk Averse, which should I choose?

Tags: probability-theory, utility

Question:  If I am slightly risk averse which do I prefer. (Give a mathematical justification for your conclusion):

[0.5, \$450; 0.5, \$400] or [0.1, \$4375; 0.9, \$0]

Okay so I get that the risk averse person would choose the first option ([0.5, \$450; 0.5, \$400]), but how can I show that mathematically?  Simply summing the probabilities times the result doesn't give the right answer, as 0.1*4375 > 0.5*$450+0.5*400.

Edit:  Using the following utility function:

```
U(Sk+n) = -263.31 + 22.09*log(n + 150,000)
```

Where n is the additional wealth you'd gain (this is new to me, let me know if we need more information... this is just a generic utility function found in a book).

This results in the following values

```
[-148.91593453] and [-148.915753041]
```

Comment: OP says:  "If I am slightly risk averse ... "  Without specifying the utility function, there is no answer to this question. I might be "slightly' risk averse, but not sufficiently so to take the lower expected payoff of the 50:50 model.

Comment: I added a utility function.  Thanks for your comment.  If more information is needed about the utility function let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, summing the probabilities times the payoff reflects a situation of indifference to risk, in fact you're computing the expected value, without considering risk aversion (this explains why a computation of that kind would suggest to take the gamble). The mathematical object that fits your problem is a concave function. This function is called utility function, let's denote it by $u$. We say that your utility function denotes risk aversion if it satisfies the following:

\begin{equation}
u(\sum x p_x)\geq \sum u(x)p_x
\end{equation}

where the sum is taken over all the possible payoffs $x$ weighted with their probability $p_x$. The point is that there are plenty of these functions, and all determine behaviours which are different: you see from your example that the player has to be strongly averse to risk not to take his chances.

Notice that if you let $u$ equal to the identity, you get an equality above. This tells you that the identity (it is the function you were using in the example) describes risk indifference.

Comment: How were you able to tell that the player must be strongly averse to risk not to take his chances?  I get that there are a number of different potential utility functions.  Did you graph the results of a couple different ones?

Comment: I did my math wrong, there's no need for a strong aversion. Have you tried plugging in your numbers in the utility function you added?

Comment: So the values end up being -148.91593453 for the first one, and -148.915753041 for the second one.  I get that the second one is less negative, so it would be preferred.  But how do I incorporate "slightly averse to risk" into the decision?

Comment: Changing the utility function (its parameters). How? Play a bit with the parameters, and see what happens to the decisions made by the player. You see that the logrithm gives a function that models aversion to risk (not the only one), how much aversion depends on the parameters of the function.

Comment: Ahhh so the "slightly averse to risk" needs to be built into the utility function.  Got it, thanks so much!